# Dynamically selecting a radio button in Ionic 3

Tags: angular, ionic-framework, ionic3

I have some code that dynamically selects a radio button depending on the expression but the issue is that it sometimes selects two radio buttons of a radio-group list, the code for html

```html
<ion-row>
            <ion-col col-4 no-padding class="one">
              <ion-item>
                <ion-label>
                  <img src="assets/imgs/nearby/male.png"> Male</ion-label>
                <ion-radio [checked]="this.gender === 'Male'" value="Male" (ionSelect)="selectGender('Male')"></ion-radio>
              </ion-item>
            </ion-col>
            <ion-col col-5 no-padding class="two">
              <ion-item>
                <ion-label>
                  <img src="assets/imgs/nearby/female.png"> Female</ion-label>
                <ion-radio [checked]="this.gender === 'Female'" value="Female" (ionSelect)="selectGender('Female')"></ion-radio>
              </ion-item>
            </ion-col>
            <ion-col col-3 no-padding class="third">
              <ion-item>
                <ion-label>
                  <img src="assets/imgs/nearby/all-mf.png"> All</ion-label>
                <ion-radio [checked]="this.gender === 'all'" value="all" (ionSelect)="selectGender('all')"></ion-radio>
              </ion-item>
            </ion-col>
          </ion-row>
```

The selectGender Methods in is

```js
selectGender(gender) {
    this.gender = '';
    this.gender = gender;
  }
```

Is there a better way to achieve this? The search fields of which radio group is a part of and the search results are both part of the same page, and are being hidden and viewed on onSearchClicked() which is a method that alters a variable which control viewing and not viewing of elements.

I want the radio button to be selected in sync with the value of gender variable in .ts file.

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like this:

```
  gender: string = "Male";

  constructor(public navCtrl: NavController) {

  }

 selectGender(gender) {
    this.gender = gender;
  }
```

default you can consider gender as 'Male', see example     [ionic-radio-group](https://stackblitz.com/edit/ionic-sysdoo)

Comment: Unfortunately this doesn't work, it allows selecting two buttons at a time, maybe due to delay in checking for and updating values

Comment: whats the issue??

Answer (score 0):

I since found a solution, binding to hidden property solves it since *ngIf removes and adds elements to DOM every-time. I should've mentioned that in the question, but use attribute binding instead of *ngIf.